# Spring Boot ClassPathResource in a JAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot 1.5 application I use `ClassPathResource` to read a static file the application JAR:

```
// ...
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class MyService {
    private Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("a.txt");
    private List<String> myStrings;
    public MyService() {
        myStrings = load(resource);
    }

    private List<String> load(Resource resource) {
        try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(resource.getURI()))) {
            myStrings = stream.filter(/* my filter */)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException x) {
            log.error("Failed to read '{}'.", resource.getFilename());
        }
    }
}
```

but this fails with:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:171) ~[zipfs.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:157) ~[zipfs.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:143) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at MyService.load(MyService.java:53) ~[classes!/:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    //...
```

How can I read a `ClassPathResource` embedded in my application JAR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JDK's `Paths.get` cannot resolve resources within JAR files so replace:

```
    Files.lines(Paths.get(resource.getURI()))
```

with:

```
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream())).lines();
```